# Не работает скрипт. Ни как не реагирует на нажатие кнопки

Tags: jquery

Html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="name" name="name"></br> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" name="email"></br> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Тема сообщения" id="subject" name="subject"></br> 
  <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></br>
<input type="button" name="done" id="done" value="Отправить">
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#done").click(function({
   var name= $("#name").val();
   var email= $("#email").val();
   var subject= $("#subject").val();
   var message= $("#message").val();
   var fail="";
if(name.length<3) fail="Имя не меньше трех символов";
   else if(email.split('@').length-1==0||email.split('.').length-1==0)
       fail="Вы ввели некорректный email";
   else if(subject.length<5)
        fail="Тема сообщения не менее 5 символов";
   else if(message.length<20)
        fail="Сообщение не менее 20 символов";
   if(fail!=""){
        $('#messageShow').html(fail+"<div class='clear'><br></div>");
        $('#messageShow').show();
        return false;           
                }
$.ajax({
    url:'/ajax/feedback.php',
    type:'POST',
    cache: false,
    data:{'name':name,'email':email,'subject':subject,'message':message},
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(data){                
      $('#messageShow').html(data+"<div class='clear'><br></div>");
      $('#messageShow').show();
    }

  });
 });
});
```

Comment: А где, собственно, сама кнопка? Не могли бы вы предоставить `html`? А также рассказать: не появляется ли какая ошибка в консоли при нажатии?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке не появляется. просто при нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="leftCol">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="name" name="name"></br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" name="email"></br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Тема сообщения" id="subject" name="subject"></br>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></br>
    <div id="messageShow"></div>
    <input type="button" name="done" id="done" value="Отправить">
   </div>
   <?php require_once"/blocks/rightCol.php"?>
  </div>
  
  <?php require_once"/blocks/footer.php"?>
  
 </body>
</html>

Comment: добавьте разметку `html` в вопрос, нажав `править`

Comment: Вот код кнопки. он находится ниже предыдущего кода

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде опечатка. В этом месте отсутствует закрывающая скобка:

```
$("#done").click(function({
```

Должно быть так:

```
$("#done").click(function(){
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам добрый человек. добра Вам

Comment: @user198744 и вы говорите что у вас никаких ошибок? У вас же как минимум `Uncaught SyntaxError:` должен был висеть в консоли.

Comment: @user198744, с html у вас тоже не всё в порядке. Думаю, под тегом `</br>` подразумевался `<br />`.